# Modify an argument in a pure function

Tags: haskell, side-effects

> **I am aware that I should not do this**
>
> **I am asking for dirty hacks to do something nasty**

### Goal

I wish to modify an argument in a pure function.

Thus achieving effect of pass by reference.

### Illustration

For example, I have got the following function.

```
fn :: a -> [a] -> Bool
fn a as = elem a as
```

I wish to modify the arguments passed in. Such as the list `as`.

```
as' = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pointTo as as'
```

Comment: You can't.  Even with `unsafePerformIO`, you can't adjust a linked list on the Haskell heap - GHC just doesn't provide sufficient primitives for you to perform such a manipulation.  Can you use the ST monad?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, what can I achieve with the ST monad?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question for a comment.  The ST monad allows you to use mutability locally in a pure function.   I'm sure you can find numerous resources on SO and elsewhere online.

Comment: Or one can use a [`Data.IORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-IORef.html) but again, one needs a Monad, to guarantee sequential processing.

Comment: Instead of learning how to program in Haskell like you usually program, learn to program Haskell's way. It'll blow your mind sometimes, but it'll change your brain and will both deepen and broaden your understanding.

Comment: This looks as an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You probably want to solve some other problem for which you have an idea involving mutation, hence you ask about how to perform said mutation (which Haskell was explicitly designed to forbid) instead of discussing the problem itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a common misconception that Haskell just deliberately prevents you from doing stuff it deems unsafe, though most other languages allow it. That's the case, for instance, with C++' `const` modifiers: while they are a valuable guarantee that something which is supposed to stay constant isn't messed with by mistake, it's generally assumed that the overall compiled result doesn't really change when using them; you still get basically impure functions, implemented as some assembler instructions over a stack memory frame.

What's already less known is that even in C++, these `const` modifiers allow the compiler to apply certain optimisations that can completely break the results when the references are modified (as possible with `const_cast` – which in Haskell would have *at least* “unsafe” in its name!); only the `mutable` keyword gives the guarantee that hidden modifications don't mess up the sematics you'd expect.

In Haskell, the same general issue applies, but much stronger. A Haskell function is *not* a bunch of assembler instructions operating on a stack frame and memory locations pointed to from the stack. *Sometimes* the compiler may actually generate something like that, but in general the standard is very careful not to suggest any particular implementation details. So actually, functions may get inlined, stream-fused, rule-replaced etc. to something where it totally wouldn't make sense to even think about “modifying the arguments”, because perhaps the arguments never even exist as such. The thing that Haskell guarantees is that, in a much higher-level sense, the *semantics* are preserved; the semantics of how you'd think about a function *mathematically*. In mathematics, it also doesn't make sense at all, conceptually, to talk about “modified arguments”.